# What rules are used for type inference when using Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Does anyone know where I can find a discussion on how type inference works when using Generics in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is originally specified in [Section 15.12.2.7 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#341287), as a result of the [Java Specification Requests #14](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=14).

You may also find various discussions on the subject, such as [Generics - type inference from context](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=428361&forumID=316) or [Type Argument Inference at the Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Type+Argument+Inference), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Angelika Langer's site](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information on Java generics.  She does have a discussion on [type inference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Argument%20Inference).

Answer (score 0):

i had to read the book: https://java-generics-book.dev.java.net/